# How to convert a numpy array from (2,4) to (4, 2)

Tags: python, numpy

How to convert array `a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])` to `b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])`.

So the input would be:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

And the output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

Note - `a.flatten().reshape((4, 2))` works, i'm not sure if there's a better approach though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `flatten` the numpy array as others have already pointed out. A more robust solution would be to `reshape` by flipping `shape` values. In this way, you don't have to worry about specifying `(4,2)`:

```
a = a.reshape(a.shape[1],a.shape[0])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

**Runtime test on 10000x20000 numpy array**:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((10000,20000))
>>> %timeit -n 100000 a.reshape(a.shape[1],a.shape[0])
601 ns ± 12.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit -n 100000 a.reshape(-1, a.shape[0])
520 ns ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: out of interest, why not use `.reshape(-1, a.shape[0])` ( I have only just learnt of -1)

Comment: I think that should be fine as well. Possibly better. In both cases, you don't have to worry about specifying the shape tuple.

Comment: @baxx Out of curiosity, I did a runtime test on a much larger array.  `a.reshape(-1, a.shape[0])` is marginally better in speed possibly because a.shape[1] doesn't need to estimated. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use reshape:

```
a.reshape(-1,2)
```

`-1` implicitly takes care of dimension size.

output:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]
 [7 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do `a.reshape((4, 2))` instead of flattening it and then reshaping it.